# iOS App Failed to Install

Tags: ios, air, flashdevelop

I've been browsing the internet for a solution to this issue and have found plenty of threads about the same problem, but there was either no solution found or the ones proposed didn't work.

I followed along with the [tutorial linked in the iOS text file](http://www.codeandvisual.com/2011/exporting-for-iphone-using-air-27-and-flashdevelop-part-three-generating-developer-certificates-provisioning-profiles-and-p12-files/) in the Air project template for FlashDeveop. Since I do not currently have an iOS device, I've been sending the IPA to a coworker to have him test it. When he attempts to load the application onto the iTouch, he gets an "app failed to install" with no further information on why it failed. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Here's what I've already done/checked:

- made sure the app ID in the apple portal matched the ID in the application.xml
- sent my co-worker the provision profiled used to create the IPA
- tried the test targets (fast test, fast debug, etc) as well as an "ad-hoc" build
- recreating the certificates

Its also worth noting that the app runs fine on my Android device, so I'm fairly certain that I've missed something in the certification process for iOS.

Comment: Did you provision their device's UDID?

Comment: If you mean by adding their device UDID to the Apple developer portal and then sending them the .mobileprovision file, then yes I did.

Comment: Not just adding it to the portal, but to the provisioning profile as well.  Also make sure they have the required minimum OS version.

Comment: Yes I made sure the device was checked in the provisioning profile that I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah sounds like a provisioning problem. Make sure the UDID of all devices you are targeting are in each listed provisioning profile (Note: You will need to add any additional UDID's added to the developer portal again to any provisioning profile).

Although I strongly recommend using Testflight for your circumstance, makes sending an .ipa extremely easy. [https://testflightapp.com/](http://testflightapp.com)